# Swift JSON extraction

Tags: ios, swift, nsjsonserialization

I am developing a swift iOS app and getting the following JSON response from web service. I am trying to parse and get `nextResponse` from it. I am unable to extract it. Could someone guide me to solve this?

```
listofstudents:
        ({
        studentsList =     (
                    {
                data =             (
                    "32872.23",
                    "38814.87",
                    "38915.85"
                );
                label = “name, parents and guardians”;
            }
        );
        dateList =     (
            "Apr 26, 2017",
            "Jun 10, 2017",
            "Jul 26, 2017"
        );
        firstResponse = “This school has 1432 students and 387 teachers.”;
        nextResponse = “This school has around 1400 students.”;
    })
```

Swift code:

```
    do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                print("json: \(json)")

                if let parseJSON = json {

                    let finalResponse = parseJSON["listofstudents"] as? AnyObject
                    print("listofstudents::   \(finalResponse)")

                    let nextResponse = parseJSON["nextResponse"] as? AnyObject
                    print("nextResponse::   \(nextResponse)")
         }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving valid JSON from the API ? Is the first code the response of the API or a print in Swift ?

Comment: First one is print in swift.

Comment: `print("listofstudents::   \(finalResponse)")` never prints ?

Comment: That's printed and the code i pasted first. I don't know how to retrieve  nextResponse from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextResponse` is part of the JSON structure (it's a nested node). So you should access it using:

```
typealias JSON = [String: Any]
if let finalResponse = parseJSON["listofstudents"] as? JSON {
    let nextResponse = finalResponse ["nextResponse"] as? JSON
    print("nextResponse::   \(nextResponse)")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, but use its native Swift counterpart, `Dictionary`. This is how you access dictionaries embedded inside other dictionaries:

```
do {
    guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any] else {return}
    print("json: \(json)")

    guard let finalResponse = parseJSON["listofstudents"] as? [String:Any] else {return}
    print("listofstudents::   \(finalResponse)")

    guard let nextResponse = finalResponse["nextResponse"] as? [String:Any] else {return}
    print("nextResponse::   \(nextResponse)")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your listofstudents is an array of dictionary so try to iterate it and extract it:-

```
if let finalResponse = parseJSON["listofstudents"] as? [String: Any] {
 //If your finalResponse has list then you can print all the data
  for response in finalResponse {
    let nextResponse = finalResponse ["nextResponse"] as? AnyObject
    print("nextResponse::\(nextResponse)")
  }
}
```